# R: how to assign columns to a matrix by column-name

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, columnsorting

I have an empty matrix with the right shape (cols and rows). I want to assign the columns to this matrix one at a time.

```
allf <- matrix(0, nrow = 2*h, ncol = ncol(ally))
colnames(allf)<- colnames(train)

Here, allf has columns from AA, AB.... AZ. 

Now, I want to assign the values by column name. As in:

allf.AA <- someothermatrix['xyz']
```

Comment: allf[,colnames(allf)]<- someothermatrix[,colnames(allf)] ? Don't quite get your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it.

```
allf[,'AA'] <- someothermatrix[,'xyz']
```